# Time war story - soldier name lengthens as he travels further from the battle front

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time

This is a short story I read in the late 80s. A soldier called H leaves an embattled position near a time-rift battlefront where humanity and unidentified aliens are shelling each other to prevent a crossing.

He is going on leave to see his family and travels on a series of carriages like train compartments, crossing with other travellers. As he travels back in time his name, H, expands to Had, then something like Hadril and so on until he reunites with his family. He's then suddenly recalled to action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short story; war where speed of time changes with distance from front line](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/short-story-war-where-speed-of-time-changes-with-distance-from-front-line)

Comment: @Burgi The answer is not accepted here so not a duplicate

Answer (score 23):

This is David Masson's "Traveller's Rest", previously asked about in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/short-story-war-where-speed-of-time-changes-with-distance-from-front-line).

I can't find a summary anywhere, but here's an extract from [one review](https://laurelswritingdesk.wordpress.com/2018/01/11/review-of-travellers-rest-by-david-i-masson/):

> ...as one travels south, one travels down-time (time moves slower) while as one travels north, one travels up-time – where time moves very quickly. I loved how Masson further illustrates this by abbreviating names in the up-time latitudes down to initials, while in the south (down-time), one accesses the more complete (and very lengthy!) names of places and people. This was an excellent device, and added to the puzzle.
>
> The story follows H, a soldier on the Frontier. He’s right near the sight-barrier, and the enemy is on the far side. Just twenty metres from his position. But he’s only there for a relatively short time – as he’s soon Relieved and must return to the South, where many years have passed since he left.

Comment: More information on 'Traveller's Rest' in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211146/short-story-about-people-living-in-a-different-time-streams/212138#212138)